About the solutions of $ \dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} = a^2+pb^2 $
Using theorem $IV$ from this article, is possible to prove that when $p$ is a prime $p ≡ 3\bmod4$, $x ≢ y\bmod{p}$ and $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, then the equation $ \dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} = a^2+pb^2 $ ever admits solutions for some integers $\{a, b\}$ (see proof below).
I want to know how $\{x, y\}$ can be expressed as a function of $\{a, b\}$: in case $p=3$ is easy to see that if $x= a+b$ and $y=a-b$ then ${x^3 - y^3}= 2b(a^2+3b^2) $ (of course not all the solutions have this form).
What can be said in other cases?
Proof:
When $(x - y) ≢ {0}\bmod{p}$
$ \dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} = P(p) $
where $P(p)$ is the arithmetic primitive factor of $ (x^p - y^p) $ defined in that article (p. $175$). With other considerations we can say that each one of those primitive prime factors is of the form $(2k_i p+1)$ where $k_i$ $∈ N$.
Now $q\mid{a^2+pb^2} $, with $q\nmid p$, iff $ \left(\frac{-p}{q}\right) = 1$ and equivalently $q ≡ \{q_1, q_2, q_3,..\}\bmod{4p}$
(see corollary $1.19$ in David Cox's book Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$), so being $q=2k_i p+1$, we have just $q_1=1$ and $q_2 = 2p+1$. Using that $p ≡ 3\bmod4$, we have $ \left(\frac{-p}{2p+1}\right) = 1$ and so $ \dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} = a^2+pb^2 $ ever admits solutions for some integers $\{a, b\}$.

Trying to decipher Birkhoff and Vandiver.  One thing to mention: as the class number $h(-4p)$  increases, the difference between $x^2 + p y^2 $   and its parent form, $ u^2 + uv + \frac{1+p}{4}  v^2 ,, ; ;$ increases.  For example, $x^2 + 11 y^2$ does not represent $23$  or $67$  integrally, despite these being $1 \pmod{11}$

Well, $p \pmod 8$   matters, better behaved for $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8$

First numerical  output:   for $p=11$  and $x$ up to 25, the first thing is expressing $ n =\frac{x^{11} - y^{11}}{x-y}.$   I took some subsets;   apparently when $y = -1$   and we express the outcome as $u^2 + 11 v^2,$   we can take $v = \frac{x^4 - x}{2}$
That's a start, it suggests some rational function of $x$  and $y$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
For $p=7$  we define
$$ u = \frac{ (x-y)  (2x^2 + 3xy + 2y^2 )}{  2} $$
$$ v =  \frac{xy(x+y)}{2} $$  and then
$$ u^2 + 7 v^2 = x^6 + x^5y + x^4y^2 + x^3 y^3 + x^2y^4 + xy^5 + y^6  $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
when $p=11$  define
$$  u = \frac{( x-y) (2x^4 + 3x^3  y  + x^2  y^2 + 3  x  y^3 + 2  y^4)}{  2}  $$
$$ v =  \frac{ xy(x+y)(x^2 - xy+y^2)}{  2} $$
and then
$$  u^2 + 11 v^2 = x^{10} + x^9y + x^8y^2 + x^7y^3 + x^6y^4 + x^5y^5 + x^4y^6 + x^3y^7 + x^2y^8 + xy^9 + y^{10} $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
For $p=19$ define
$$ u = \frac{ (x-y)  (2x^8 + 3x^7y - x^6y^2 + 2x^5y^3 + 7x^4y^4 + 2x^3y^5 - x^2y^6 + 3xy^7 + 2y^8 )}{ 2} $$
$$ v = \frac{  x  y  (x +y) ( x^2 -xy +y^2)(x^4 - x^2 y^2 + y^4   )}{  2} $$
after which $$ u^2 + 19 v^2 = x^{18} + x^{17}y + x^{16}y^2 + \cdots + x^2 y^{16} + x y^{17} + y^{18}  $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
I particularly focused on  $n$ being prime, so that there would be just one $u,v$ pair   with both positive.
The biggest slowdown was programming errors. Next  to find  rational function for my letter $u.$

Great! In that case $u= \dfrac1{2} (x - y) (2 x^4 + 3 x^3 y + x^2 y^2 + 3 x y^3 + 2 y^4)$. How would you approach the case $p = 7$ and others?

@user967210  given how this one worked out, I'd expect  fairly pleasant polynomials for any prime $p.$  On the other hand, I'm not sure the coefficients are going to be easy functions of $p.$   I got this because of a simple computer program, easy enough to adapt for prime $7,$   the numbers should be smaller, quicker to do any factoring steps. Slower for $p = 19,$   for example. As I try to convince the students:  the less you understand, the more important become experiments with concrete numbers. For number theory, programs in easy languages

@user967210  for $p=7$   we have $v = \frac{xy(x+y)}{2}$    More time needed to work up $p=19$

wow! Yeah of course would be really great to know how to calculate those coefficients, and maybe adding other cases some patterns will show up

@user967210  as I mentioned, this would probably look a bit better if we moved from $u^2 + p v^2 $ to the parent form $ s^2 + st + \frac{1+p}{4} t^2$  To travel back and forth just note $4s^2 + 4st + t^2 + p t^2 = (2s+t)^2 + p t^2.$  The parent form is the one fits directly with field $Q[ \sqrt{-p}]$

I guess it is possible to restate the problem in terms of cyclotomic binary form: if we define $ f(k) = y^{\phi(k)} \Phi_k(x/y) $ where $\phi(k)$ is Euler's phi function and $\Phi_k(x/y) $ is the $k$-th cyclotomic polynomial, so if $p$ is prime we have$f(p) = \dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} $ and $ f(7) = u^2 + 7\left (\dfrac{xyf(2)}{2} \right )^2$
$ f(11) = u^2 + 11\left (\dfrac{xyf(2)f(6)}{2} \right )^2$
$ f(19) = u^2 + 19\left (\dfrac{xyf(2)f(6)f(12)}{2} \right )^2$
I tried to work out some symmetries for other cases, but didn't found anything. That could be of any help?

Of course the same relations hold if we just use $\Phi_k(x)$ instead of $ f(k)$, so maybe it will be simpler to use them to find the coefficients
